# Is there any way to split this function apart and insert spaces?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I needed to output an address to the screen in the following format (with each line of the address aligned by prefixing with space characters):

```
Address: 1234 Elm St.    
         Apartment # 2 Rear  
         Anytown, NV 12345-6789
```

This is some example code that defines a free function (printAddress) that will print the address to the screen. I cannot alter the code for the printAddress function in any way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void printAddress( );

int main( )
{

    cout << "Address: ";
    printAddress ( );

    return 0;
}

void printAddress( ) 
{
    cout << "1234 Elm St." << endl;
    cout << "Apartment #2 Rear" << endl;
    cout << "Anytown, NV 12345-6789" << endl;
};
```

As of right now, the output of this code is:

```
Address: 1234 Elm St.  
Apartment #2 Rear  
Anytown, NV 12345-6789
```

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow split the function apart to insert those spaces on the second and third lines and make everything line up. Any ideas? Or is this impossible?

Comment: Maybe if you tried to multithread

Comment: Not sure what you want. If the output is always `"Address: "` followed by the address, then why not just `cout` 9 spaces before the second and third line?

Comment: @WhatsUp I cannot alter the printAddress function code. It has to remain as is. This is just a hypothetical example I thought up as I was doing one of my assignments in C++ class and was wondering if it was possible.

Comment: Is `printAddress()` really outputting hard-coded values. That makes it a pretty useless function that doesn't print generic addresses, but prints a very ***specific*** address. As such forget about it. _However_ if you have a _sensible_ `printAddress()` function, that obtains the data that it needs to print from somewhere else. ***Then*** you might have a reasonable option to achieve what you want. PS: wrt your last comment: your "hypothetical example" is impractical and _useless_. If you have a _practical_ scenario, there would be a practical solution.

Comment: I see. In this situation, it is probably impossible within C++, since it has something to do with the actual realization of `cout`. You could try to overload `cout<<endl`, but this will ruin all other part of the program...

Comment: @CraigYoung Yes you are correct. This is just an example I came up. My concern has to do with the formatting when outputting the address to the screen. In my actual assignment, the function took the address as an argument for each object that was initialized in the class. But the formatting issue was exactly the same. I just hard coded the address in this example.

Comment: No, I do have an idea of how what you're asking for can be achieved. The problem is that you'd have to do some seriously ***horrible*** things to get it working. Things you don't need to do in a practical situation. So it's pointless pursuing it. You've said you're learning. Don't start by learning ***horrible practices***.

Comment: @CraigYoung Ha, okay. I didn't realize it would take horrible practices to achieve this. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @Maisy Since you have an _actual_ assignment, reframe (and [edit]) your question in terms of an _actual_ problem. What you've done here is go half-way down the road to a solution, and now you're asking something that seems weird - _because it **is** weird_. This is known as an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You'll get much better results asking for help about your ***real*** problem rather than how to sledge-hammer your half-baked solution into something that sort of badly works.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the `std::cout`, reauthor the message, and repost it to (real) `std::cout`. Something like (haven't tested):

```
ostringstream oss;
auto oldcoutbuf = cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());
printAddress();
string s = oss.str();
s = indentMsg(s);
cout.rdbuf(oldcoutbuf);
cout << "Address: " << s;
```

(Probably known as "seriously ***horrible*** things to get it working".)

`printAddress` function is simply badly designed.

Comment: Your code [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12de91bf73ad67c8). It should be noted that it's not safe for multi-threading (and can't possibly be).

Comment: @zett42 I only mention multithreading is because cout is not thread safe

Comment: @zett42 "can't possibly be" seems incorrect. As always, the threads simply need to coordinate their use of shared resources... I do not code it in thread-safe manner, but I don't see why it would be "thread impossible".